# Debugging C Linked List Program caught in infinite loop

Tags: c, linked-list

So this is a very simple program to create and display a linked list. Here I'm getting caught in the display loop, and I'm seeing infinite '2->2->2->...' on screen.

After debugging, I can see that my program ALWAYS goes into the `if` statement of `insertNode()` whereas it should only go there ONCE i.e. when the linked list is initialized.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
};

struct node * head = NULL;
struct node * curr = NULL;

void insertNode(struct node * temp2) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp2;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        temp2->next = head;
        head = temp2;
    }
}

void display() {
    curr = head;
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d->",curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

void main() {
    struct node * temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = 5;
    insertNode(temp);
    temp->data = 6;
    insertNode(temp);
    temp->data = 1;
    insertNode(temp);
    temp->data = 2;
    insertNode(temp);
    display();

}
```

Comment: it is better if you move `curr` inside of display instead of polluting the global area if you only use it in there. try to avoid globals as much as possible.

Comment: also check in `display` so that `head` really points to something before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 2):

You should allocate and create new node for each data when inserting it in the linked list.

```
void main() {
    struct node * temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = 5;
    insertNode(temp);

    temp = malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = 6;
    insertNode(temp);

    temp = malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = 1;
    insertNode(temp);

    temp = malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = 2;
    insertNode(temp);
    display();

}
```

As you are using same node to add as multiple nodes, its making the circular list.

Your `insertNode()` looks ok.

Comment: Is the cast in the first malloc really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting next of `temp2` to head, and then head to `temp2`. So in fact next node of `temp2` is `temp2`, that's why you have infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

In you main you have one pointer to the temp and you continue inserting the same node and it ends up pointing to itself. You now have a circular list that's why you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an infinite loop because you only have one node. Doing `temp->data = 5;` and then `temp->data = 6;` does not create a new node. So when you add the same node into the list again, the `next` pointer in the node points to itself. So your while loop in display never terminates, because the `next` node is always the current node.